# Android Camera Permission -> PlayStore

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I want to publish my game on the Google PlayStore and Amazon. It uses the camera, so I added the camera permission to the manifest file. Now I'd like to know if I have to check if a camera is available on the device inside the app or if the app doesn't appear in the store on devices without a camera. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permission is only a permission.

If you want to force your app to require a camera you do it like this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  This forces the PlayStore/Amazon store to show the app only on devices with a camera?

Comment: @user4256826 that is correct for the Play Store, not sure about amazon, but probably too.